# Android setting multiple long date alarms

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm trying to create a function in my App, which notifies the user at the expiration day of his rented books. I'll work with checkboxes in a listview, as below:

[image: No description]

*(Dates are for show purposes only)*

Now i'm wondering how can i do it the best way. I'm having experiences with AlarmManager and BroadcastReceivers, but I didn't get a clear flowchart yet.

Thats because I need to set an **specific alarm to each book** and **cancel that specific alarm** when requested. Also, it needs to reactivate all Alarms when device is restared (by calling BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast).

PS.: Alarms will usually be set to one week after current date.

PS2.: Can I use Calendar to do it? I mean, this way i wouldn't have to reactivate all alarms, or calculate (expirationDate - currentDate) in millis.

Can someone, who has an idea, try to show me the way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the key would be to give each and every book its own alarm id as soon as you set the alarm for this book for the first time.

Then you should keep a list of the running alarm ids and timestamps (maybe in SharedPreferences).

With a method like this you can cancel a specific alarm with regards to its alarm id:

```
public static void cancelAlarm(Context context, int alarmId) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, alarmId,
            new Intent(context, YourService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if(pi!=null) {
       AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       am.cancel(pi);
    }
}
```

When you receive the BOOT broadcast, you can get the list of alarm ids together with timestamps from SharedPreferences and start all the alarms with their respective alarm ids